# Recursively get documents in Azure Cosmos Stored Procedure

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to generate a content tree for a simple wiki. Each page has a Children property that stores the id of other wiki pages. I'm trying to write a SPROC that gets all of the documents, then iterate over each page's Children property and replace each item with an actual wiki page document. I'm able to get the first set of documents, but the wikiChildQuery returns `undefined` and I'm not quite sure why.

I've been able to get a document with the query alone but for some reason, it doesn't work within the SPROC. Is there something I'm missing here?

```
function GetWikiMetadata(prefix) {
    var context = getContext();
    var collection = context.getCollection();
    var metadataQuery = 'SELECT {\"ExternalId\": p.ExternalId, \"Title\": p.Title, \"Slug\": p.Slug, \"Children\": p.Children} FROM Pages p'

    var metadata = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), metadataQuery, {}, function (err, documents, options) {
        if (err) throw new Error('Error: ', + err.message);

        if (!documents || !documents.length) {
            throw new Error('Unable to find any documents');
        } else {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();

            for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
                var children = documents[i]['$1'].Children;

                if (children.length) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
                        var child = children[j];

                        children[j] = GetWikiChildren(child);
                    }
                }
            }

            response.setBody(documents);
        }
    });

    if (!metadata) throw new Error('Unable to get metadata from the server');

    function GetWikiChildren(child) {
        var wikiChildQuery = metadataQuery + ' WHERE p.ExternalId = \"' + child + '\"';

        var wikiChild = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), wikiChildQuery, {}, function(err, document, options) {
            if (err) throw new Error('Error: ', + err.message);

            if (!document) {
                throw new Error('Unable to find child Wiki');
            } else {
                var children = document.Children;

                if (children) {
                    for (var k = 0; k < children.length; k++) {
                        var child = children[k];

                        children[k] = GetWikiChildren(child);
                    }
                } else {
                    return document;
                }
            }

            if (!wikChild) throw new Error('Unable to get child Wiki details');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.I'm able to get the first set of documents, but the wikiChildQuery
>   returns undefined and I'm not quite sure why.

Firstly, here should be corrected. In the first loop, you get children array with `documents[i]['$1'].Children`, however , in the `GetWikiChildren` function you want to get children array with `document.Children`? Surely,it is `undefined`. You need to use `var children = document[0]['$1'].Children;`

> 2.It seems that you missed the replaceDocument method.

You could refer to the snippet code of your `metaDataQuery` function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
            var children = documents[i]['$1'].Children;

            if (children.length) {
                for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
                    var child = children[j];

                    children[j] = GetWikiChildren(child);
                }
            }
            documents[i]['$1'].Children = children;
            collection.replaceDocument(doc._self,doc,function(err) {
                             if (err) throw err;
                 });
        }
```

> 3.Partial update is not supported by Cosmos db SQL Api so far but it is hitting the road.

So, if your sql doesn't cover your whole columns,it can't be done for your replace purpose.([feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6693091-be-able-to-do-partial-updates-on-document)) It is important to note that the columns which is not mentioned in the replace object would be devoured while using `replaceDocument` method.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you for your response Jay! Your first suggestion was key. I wasn't accessing the values correctly. From there I was able to figure everything else out.